# CORS issue with swagger

Tags: svn, cors, swagger, swagger-ui

We are trying to host api spec yml file in our svn repository which is hosted on another server. When we are pointing to yml file from this server we are getting cors error in swagger-ui.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable [CORS](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/cors.md) on the server that hosts your YAML file. How you do this depends on the server you use. This site has instructions for many server types: https://enable-cors.org/server.html